# PubNub Rails example application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pubnub

Is there a PubNub example application built on Rails out there? I'm having a hard time finding one, but it would really helpful in order for me to figure out how to configure PubNub on Rails.

Anything along the lines of some sort of chat application would be perfect for learning purposes. So far I've only found a Sinatra app, Chatterbee, but I'm kind of intimidated to try to convert it over since I've never used Sinatra before.

I'd really like to find this, and any help would be much appreciated. I'm not an expert in web development, so specifically a Rails application would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find one, but in case someone is interested, here's [ChatterBee.](https://github.com/ready4god2513/ChatterBee)

Comment: I think @Anil Kumar Muppalla on the same page pointed at more specific implementation, you were asking .You should mark that thing as answer so that people get the more specific implementation to understand - Don't mind plz just a correction :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a pubnub rails application [Pubnub Livestream](https://github.com/pubnub/ruby/tree/master/examples/pubnub_livestream)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Heroku that very easily integrates with rails, it also has a plugin for pubnub:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pubnub